# Only getting html standard tooltips when using bootstrap tooltips

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to use the bootstrap tooltips on an element by I am not getting the bootstrap style, only the html style:

[image]

I have used these many times, but I feel like I have been up for too long and am getting sloppy... can someone point me to the error?

code:

home.php

```
<a href="#" id='award-value' rel='tooltip' data-toggle='tooltip' title='My Tooltip'>450</a>



<script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>    
    <script src='assets/js/chosen.jquery.js'></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
        $(".chzn-select").chosen(); 
        $(".chzn-select-deselect").chosen({
            allow_single_deselect:true
        }); 
    </script>
    <script src="assets/js/jquery-form.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/session.js"></script>
```

and I am including the bootstrap css

---

EDIT:
I fixed it, I had the elements i wanted to be tooltips added dynamically, fetched using ajax... I just put the $(this).tooltip() in the success callback of the .ajax() call like so:

```
function fetch_live_feed(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url:"includes/php/live_feed.php",
        success:function(data){
            $("#live-feed-loading-port").html(data);
            $(".live-feed-row a").tooltip();
        }
    });
}
```

Please let me know if this is a wrong thing to do...

Thanks :)

Comment: is your doctype set to `<!DOCTYPE HTML>`?  Skipping that can cause issues with some of the plugins

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">

Comment: Can you switch to `<!DOCTYPE HTML>` to see if it fixes this? (without creating other issues that is)

Comment: nope it didn't fix it

Comment: drat... and you can confirm that bootstrap.js includes the tooltip plugin?